# react HOC with implicit return, code review

Tags: reactjs

how to change that code to use  implicit return.

```
import components from 'core/components';
import RTE from 'core/components/RTE';
import withSelect from './withSelect';

components.rte.component = withSelect(props => {
  return <RTE {...props} />;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```js
// imports

components.rte.component = withSelect(props => <RTE {...props} />);

// rest
```